# Excel sheet comparison - any order

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I'm looking for a way to compare one Excel sheet with another. 
Is there a way to compare whole records, without regard to the order of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work...  The columns may have to be modified a bit depending on the width.

```
Private Sub CompareSheets()
Dim first_index As Integer
Dim last_index As Integer
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Integer
Dim r2 As Integer
Dim found As Boolean

Set sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
Set sheet2 = Worksheets(2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

first_index = 1
last_index = sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r2 = first_index To last_index
    found = False
    For r1 = first_index To last_index
        If sheet1.Cells(r1, 16) = sheet2.Cells(r2, 9) Then
        ' Found match.
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r1


    If Not found Then
        ' Do something if the if we did not find it???
    End If
Next r2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @dirtyw0lf   If you found this acceptable please click on the large downward facing arrow to "Accept" this and then you can click on the upwards facing arrow to indicate that it was useful, if you desire. Thanks...

Comment: getting error for last_index = sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Counatb).End(xlUp).Row, what verion of excel are you running?